# HTML5 - padding under Canvas element causing alignment issues

Tags: html, canvas

How do I align these two both at the top of the div or just get rid of the space at the bottom of the canvas?

```
<style>
    html, body, div, canvas {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
<div style="border: solid 1px Grey;">
    <a style="border: solid 1px Grey">Test</a>
    <canvas style="border: solid 1px Grey;width:30px;height: 30px"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the div `position:relative` and both the anchor & canvas as `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        .Left {
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid red;
            width: 30px;
        }
        .Right {
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid green;
            width: 35px;
        }
        .Outer {
            border: solid 1px Grey;
            height: 50px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Outer">
        <div class="Left"><a style="border: solid 1px Grey">Test</a></div>
        <div class="Right">
            <canvas style="border: solid 1px Grey;width:30px;height:30px">
                <!--Your Canvas-->
            </canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```